# "Can't reallocate empty Mat with locked layout (probably due to misused 'const' modifier)" in function 'create'. What does this error mean?

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am trying to make a ML Model using opencv technique Super Resolution for image enhancement tasks. I got my code from chatgpt. It's all accurately executed but when I try to execute the model, it gives me this error. I have implemented a pre-trained model EDSR with the .pb extension.

I tried to get my model trained but it's giving me this error for the past 2 days. I have done all the measure given from chatgpt by checking the image path, file directories and extensions.

Here is my code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Load the image
image = cv2.imread('C:/Users/HP/Desktop/IMG Enhancement/test2.png')

# Define the super-resolution model
sr_model = cv2.dnn_superres.DnnSuperResImpl_create()

# Load a pre-trained super-resolution model (e.g., "edsr" or "lapsrn")
sr_model.readModel("EDSR_x2.pb")
sr_model.setModel("edsr", 3)  # You can choose the scale factor (e.g., 2, 3, 4)

# Perform super-resolution
enhanced_image = sr_model.upsample(image)
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
\<ipython-input-11-1f7a95708357\> in \<cell line: 2\>()
1 # Perform super-resolution
\----\> 2 enhanced_image = sr_model.upsample(image)

error: OpenCV(4.8.0) /io/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix_wrap.cpp:1286: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !(m.empty() && fixedType() && fixedSize()) && "Can't reallocate empty Mat with locked layout (probably due to misused 'const' modifier)" in function 'create'
```

Comment: getting this also when trying to implement dnn_superres